# Mongoose query in array for retrieving elements starting from index 0 to n where n is the position of the element from the last

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to return all elements of my array which appear before a particular position in the array from the last, for example see below example.

var arr = [59, 34, 6, 9, 45, 67, 89, 56, 34, 26, 56, 45]
now for position = 5 which means 5th position from the last which is 56 i want to get array [56, 89, 67, 45, 9, 6, 34, 59]

**Mongoose Schema**

```
var user_coupons_schema = new Schema({
mobile_no: {type: String, unique: true},
coupons: [{type: String}]
});
```

**Mongoose query**

```
usercoupons.findOne({mobile_no: mobile_no}, {'_id':0, coupons: { "$slice": [-skip, limit]}}, function(err, docs) {
```

**Update**

Using Aggregation my code is given below but can someone please tell me why below value is coming NaN inside $slice

> "arr_size" - skip -> NaN

```
usercoupons.aggregate(
        { $match : {mobile_no: mobile_no} },
        { $project: {arr_size: {$size: "$coupons"}} },
        { $project: {_id:0, coupons: { "$slice": [0, "arr_size" - skip]}} },
        function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Hii1');
            } else {
                if (docs) {
                    console.log('Hii2');
                } else {
                    console.log('Hii3');
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Can provide more info on the schema and show what you've tried?

Comment: i want to use slice but as in slice[skip, limit] there are two paramters for skip i can use -position but i don't know for limit what should i use ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you simply have a JavaScript array based on your comment.

```
var arr = [59, 34, 6, 9, 45, 67, 89, 56, 34, 26, 56, 45];
var ind = 5;
var subset = arr.slice(0, arr.length - ind + 1); // if you want to include value at ind'th position from the last
// OR    
var subset = arr.slice(0, arr.length - ind); // if you don't want to include value at ind'th position from the last
```

Comment: I dont have a simple javascript array i mean i have a schema which have a simple array please look at my edited post.

Comment: @PrakashKumar, You could get the `doc`, then process the array the way I have shown above. Another option would be to use MongoDB `aggregate()` method to get the `size` of the array and `slice` it before returning the doc.

Comment: i only want elements betwen 0 to n that's why i dont wanna go with first option, can you please write aggregate query method ??

Comment: are you there ?? can you please tell me the aggregate query code.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the aggregate query code ??

Comment: can you please have a look at my updated question ??

Comment: can you please have a look at my updated question ??